# double slash in URLs.

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route, zend-acl, zend-router

Zend Route issue.

Normally it works fine.

```
http://www.example.com/course-details/1/Physics-Newtons-Law
```

But if I type in an extra slash in the url, the noauthAction of my Error controller gets called.

Example of URL's that are not working.

```
http://www.example.com/course-details//1/Physics-Newtons-Law
http://www.example.com/course-details/1//Physics-Newtons-Law
```

Is there something I need to set in the route definition to allow extra slashes?

Routing in application.ini

```
resources.router.routes.viewcourse.route = "/course-details/:course_id/:title"
resources.router.routes.viewcourse.defaults.controller = course
resources.router.routes.viewcourse.defaults.action = view
resources.router.routes.viewcourse.defaults.title = 
resources.router.routes.viewcourse.reqs.course_id = "\d+"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a controller plugin to fix common URL typos.

```
/**
 * Fix common typos in URLs before the request
 * is evaluated against the defined routes.
 */
class YourNamespace_Controller_Plugin_UrlTypoFixer 
    extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function routeStartup($request)
    {
        // Correct consecutive slashes in the URL.
        $uri = $request->getRequestUri();
        $correctedUri = preg_replace('/\/{2,}/', '/', $uri);
        if ($uri != $correctedUri) {
            $request->setRequestUri($correctedUri);
        }
    }
}
```

And then register the plugin in your ini file.

```
resources.frontController.plugins.UrlTypoFixer = "YourNamespace_Controller_Plugin_UrlTypoFixer"
```

Comment: Thanks Zach - that fixed it for me. I was going down the wrong path - I was playing around with ReWrite rules of apache to remove double slashes - but this one was quick n easy. Thanks

Comment: Aslo be aware that if you give the router routes via a config file in your boostrapper with $router->addConfig($config, 'routes'); it's not actually adding routes too the already existing ones (defaults) but overriding them.. to really add them make sure you do $router->addDefaultRoutes(); before you do the addConfig